# get the real address(or index in vTable) of virtual member function

Tags: c++, member-functions

In c++ is there any way to get the **real address** of member function, or the **index** in vTable ?

**Updated:**

**I don't know the INDEX in vTable** and 
**I don't know the address**

Here's **why** I want to know this:

I want to hook the function **ID3DXFont->DrawText** of DirectX. If I know the index of the **DrawText** in the vTable, I can replace it to do the hook. But how to get the index? If it's able to get the the real address, I can search it in the vTable to get the index.

And not particularly **ID3DXFont->DrawText**, maybe some other functions in the future, so I'm trying to write a generic hook function.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct cls {
    virtual int fn1() {
        cout << "fn1 called" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    virtual int fn2() {
        cout << "fn2 called" << endl;
        return 2;
    }
};

template <typename fn_t>
DWORD fn_to_addr(fn_t fn) { // convert function to DWORD for printing
    union U {
        fn_t fn;
        DWORD addr;
    };
    U u;
    u.fn = fn;
    return u.addr;
}

int main() {
    cls c;

    DWORD addr = fn_to_addr(&cls::fn2);
    cout << hex << addr << endl;
}
```

In debug mode, the code above outputs the address of **jump table**. 
And in release mode, the **&cls::fn2** returns **0x00401058**, which points to some optimized code:

```
00401058   .    mov     eax, dword ptr [ecx] // get vptr
0040105A   .    jmp     dword ptr [eax+4] // jmp to the second function (fn2)
```

Both are not the real address. Anyway to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a quite trick question. Since you are using virtual method it depend on the compiler you are using.

Comment: Not possible in general. However, read about [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), and explain why you are asking your question.... (why does the machine address of functions matters to you?)!

Comment: @aj3423 what do you mean by the term "real address"? How about virtual memory concept?

Comment: I think it's good to add it on next c++ standard ..

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Thanks, thread updated, comments added for why doing this.

Comment: The values you show for release mode looks like a trampoline to the actual function.  In both release mode and debug mode, you'll have to get the address of the object you want to call the function on into ECX (assuming MSC, which seems safe, given the use of ECX in the code and your use of DWORD).  I don't know how you expect to do that in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give up so easily!

While the other answers are correct in saying that the C++ language doesn't allow you to do this in a portable way, there's an important factor in your particular case that may make this a more reasonable thing to do.

The key is that ID3DXFont is a COM interface and the exact binary details of how those work are specified separately from the language used to access them. So while C++ doesn't say what you'll find at the other end of that pointer, COM *does* say that there's a vtable there with an array of function pointers in a specified order and with a specified calling convention. This allows me to tell you that the index of the DrawText function is <del>3</del>14 (DrawTextA) or 15 (DrawTextW) and that this will still be true in Visual C++ 28.0 many years from now. Or in GCC 8.3.1 for that matter: since COM is a binary interface specification, all compilers are supposed to implement it the same way (if they claim to support COM).

Have a look at the second link below for a ready-made implementation of COM function hooking using two different methods. Approach#2 is the closest to what you're asking for but I think you may want to consider the first one instead because it involves less voodoo.

Sources:

[[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573(v=vs.85).aspx]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%5d)
[[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153096/Intercepting-Calls-to-COM-Interfaces]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153096/Intercepting-Calls-to-COM-Interfaces%5d)
[[http://goodrender.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/include/d3dx9core.h]](http://goodrender.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/include/d3dx9core.h%5d)

Comment: Why the index of DrawText in vtable is 14 on my machine (win7 32bit + vs2010 + debug mode)

Comment: @aj3 Sorry, I assumed the functions were listed in interface order in MSDN but they are simply in alphabetical order. You are correct: it's 14 (or 15 for UTF-16 version). Answer updated. But I assure you, this does not depend on your machine, compiler or compiler settings.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing anywhere near portable.  Your attempt using
`&cls::fn2` can't work, since the results must work in cases
like `(pCls->*fn)()` even when `pCls` points to a derived class
which overrides the function.  (Pointers to member functions are
complicated beasts, which identify whether the function is
virtual or not, and provide different information depending on
this.  And if you're experimenting with MSC, be aware that you
have to specify `/vmg` for pointers to member functions to work
correctly.)

Even for a given implementation, you need an instance of the
correct type.  Given that, *if* you know the class layout, and
the layout of the virtual function table, you can track it down.
Typically, the pointer to the virtual function table is the 
first word in the class, although this is not guaranteed.  And
usually, the functions will appear in the order they are
declared.  Along with additional information, however, like
pointers to the RTTI, and possibly offset information required
to fix up the `this` pointer when calling the function (although
many compilers will use a trampoline for this).  For 64 bit g++
under Windows (CygWin version):

```
struct C
{
    virtual ~C() {}
    virtual void fn1() const { std::cout << "In C::fn1\n"; }
    virtual void fn2() const {}
};

void const*
fn1ToAddr( C const* pC )
{
    void const* const* vPtr = *reinterpret_cast<void const* const* const*>(pC);
    return vPtr[2];
}
```

`fn1ToAddr` returns the address of `fn1` for the object passed
to it; if the object is of type `C`, it returns the address of
`C::fn1`, and if it is of a derived type which overrides `fn1`,
it returns the address of the overriding function.

Whether this works all of the time or not, I cannot say; I think
g++ uses trampolines in cases of multiple inheritance, for
example (in which case, the returned address would be the
address of the trampoline).  And it might not work the next
major release of g++.  (For the version of MSC I have at hand,
replacing the index `2` with `1` seems to work.  But again,
I only tried very simple cases.  There are absolutely no
guarantees.)

Basically, you would *never* want to do anything like this in
production code.  It can be useful, however, if you're trying to
understand how the compiler works.

EDIT:

Re your edit with the why?  Just because you have the address
(maybe), it doesn't mean that you can call the function.  You
cannot call a member function without an object, and depending
on any number of things, you may not be able to pass the
function the object.  (With MSC, for example, the object will
usually be passed in ECX.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain why at first, thread is now updated. I don't know the index either, if I know that I can get the address.

Comment: @aj3423 The index will vary from one compiler to the next, and as I point out, may _not_ be sufficient.  For simple cases, the entries in the table are in the order of the virtual functions declared in the class (with any virtual functions it the class' base classes first).  There may be some additional entries, either at the start or at the end, and each entry may contain some additional information.  And of course, the calling sequence for a member function may be different than that of a normal function (the case with MSC, for example).

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table):

> Whenever a class defines a virtual function (or method), most
>   compilers add a hidden member variable to the class which points to a
>   so-called virtual method table (VMT or Vtable). This VMT is basically
>   an array of pointers to (virtual) functions.

as far as I know, you don't have access to the Vtable, the compiler doesn't even know the number of entries in the table.

Comment: Actually, the compiler knows more about the layout of the vtable than you do.

Comment: but on compile time the compiler doesn't know which function each entry in the vtable should point to, the base class function or the derived class function. the entries are set on runtime.

Comment: Clearly, since the entry can point to different functions at different times.  But _you_ don't even know which entry, if any, is relevant to the function you are interested in.